# Setting up a deep learning architecture for multi-dimensional data

Tags: deep-learning, convolutional-neural-networks, model-request

The input data is thousands, millions of 4x1000 matrices. Each row consists of 3 small natural numbers (1000 combinations) and a corresponding real number between 0 and 1.

The output is a 1x1000 vector for each of the matrices. Each output vector value [1 or 0] is not defined by the corresponding 4-argument entry, but the whole 4x1000 matrix. Each input matrix defines a few valid output 1x1000 vectors that cannot be computed analytically from the 4x1000 matrices.

What would be the options for setting up a deep learning architecture to try to tackle this challenge?

Comment: Maybe you should describe the nature of your data and not just their dimensions and what task are you trying to solve.